# How to display a "loading" dialog while navigating between pages?

Tags: jquery, blackberry, cordova

So, my phonegap application has to work on a blackberry with OS 5. This has brought a lot of problems during the developing of the app. Initially, i had jquery-mobile, then, since blackberry cannot handle it (awful transitions, very long loading times, out of memory errors at random times) I decided to keep the logic of the app and take out jquery mobile, re-creating the interfaces in html. This worked, in fact, the app runs cleanly in BBOS 6 and android. In BB5, the app runs fine, but sometimes the loading times are a bit long.

The application was splitted into 4 different .html files, some of which contain tabs that are used to load data dinamically using ajax calls. The **ajax calls work fine** and take 2-4 seconds to show the content.  The transition between pages, however, takes a lot of time: 15-20 seconds. What I would like to do is to display some kind of "loading..." message **when navigating from one page to another** so the user know that the app is working fine and it will just take some time.

Blackberry does not change the cursor image to a clock always so there's just a black page which leaves the user waiting for some time. Is there a way to notify that content is loading to the user while navigating between pages?

I know this could be done loading contents with ajax calls, but splitting the app in different pages allows me to lower the weight of the application in order for it to work on BB OS5.

Any advices on this? any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is most of the time spend? Do you find that the page you are currently on, pauses for a large amount of time before it finally gets the next page and the new page then loads quickly? 

If this is the case like i've had in the passed. We created a floating Div that has a animated loading gif in it. You could either position this in the middle of the page and have a overlay under it or have no overlay and place it in the top left corner..

Comment: After clicking to navigate to the next page, it changes to a black screen in almost no time, then spends like 15 seconds loading the next page. When page starts loading, it takes almost no time to make the ajax call and add the dinamically created content.

Comment: you may find this very hard to handle then. I would have hoped the browser doesn't clear the page until the new one is actually ready. do you know what causes a 15-20 seconds transition... that is a very long time

Comment: It's just the BB OS5 that takes a long time to load a page. It's browser is not capable of much. Since OS6 or OS7 they switched to a webkit based browser, which works MUCH MUCH MUCH better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no standard way of doing it. but there is a way around , I did long ago.

When a navigation link is clicked, you just open a small popup saying "Loading, Please wait" and then navigate to the clicked link. and when the target page is fully loaded, write some script to unload the popup.

Comment: I guess going with that, you could *shudder* open the clicked link up in another hidden frame.. once loaded which that frame into view and hide a loading message!

Comment: @Steve doing it that way would require to use ajax calls. I thought about this, except that i'm afraid that loading so many pages/elements/ajaxresponses the performance of the BB will drop A LOT.

Comment: Rab, are you positive that a popup would stay on the display until next page is loaded? My understanding is that a popup is part of the page that called it, and unloading that page would unload the popup as well. Or not?

Comment: Yeah I am positive. Popup is an separate entity. when it is opened.

Comment: actually it isn't. I tried to do this with a normal javascript alert, and it didn't work. However, using the "notification api" of phonegap, the popup stays in place while loading the next page. All there's left to do is close the popup on it's own when the new page loads.

Comment: I am happy you found your way out.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for. It looks like there's no way of modifying the dialog, or taking out the buttons, or disabling them, or auto-closing it.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, however I have been looking for a solution to this and I have found that this works best

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
         showLoader(); //opens up a bootstrap modal with some animating loader icon
    });
</script>
```

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) this works on all modern browsers.